# regex lookaround and match IF

Tags: regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds

I'm a bit stuck on trying to figure out how to get lookaround to work for me in regards to an if-else type situation. When I try to implement the if-else idiom on [this site](https://regex101.com/#python) I end up with an error. Here's what I have:

```
MCV(1|0)(\d)(?<!1)\1[0-6]|[0-9]
```

And this is an example of what I'm trying to match

These

```
MVC123 MVC034 MVC001 MVC196
```

Not these

```
MCV197 MCV000 MCV876
```

Thus matching where `MCV` appears and the number component ranges from 1-196

Comment: Just a note: `(\d)(?<!1)` = `[02-9]`, and `(1|0)` is leff efficient than `([01])`. What are the actual requirements? Could you formulate them?

Comment: Updated the question for a little bit more clarity.

Comment: I would use [`^(?:\s*MCV(?:00[1-9]|0[1-9][0-9]|1[0-8][0-9]|19[0-6])\b)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/zF0lY4/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your regex broken down:

```
MCV(1|0)(\d)(?<!1)\1[0-6]|[0-9]
```

1. `MCV` - match *MCV* literally
2. `(1|0)` - match `1` or `0`
3. `(\d)` - match a digit
4. `(?<!1)` - make sure that last digit wasn't a `1`
5. `\1` - match exactly what the first group matched (aka if `(1|0)` matched `1` - match `1`, otherwise - `0`)
6. `[0-6]` - match a digit from `0` to `6`
7. `|[0-9]` - alternatively, match all of the above **or** just a digit  from `0` to `9`

As to what a real solution would be:

```
MVC(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|1[0-8]\d|19[0-6])
```

The 1-196 part:

1. `00[1-9]` - if we start with `00`, the third digit shouldn't be a `0`, aka **1 to 9**
2. `0[1-9]\d` - if we start with `0` and a second digit, which isn't a `0` then any digit is acceptable for third position, aka **10 to 99**
3. `1[0-8]\d` - if we start with `1` and a second digit, which isn't `9` then any digit is acceptable for third position, aka **100 to 189**
4. `19[0-6]` - if we start with `19` then only digits from `0` to `6` are acceptable for third position, aka **190 to 196**

Comment: That makes much more sense (explicitly defining the instances) rather than what I was trying to do. Thanks for the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
\bMVC(0*[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-8][0-9]|19[0-6])\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vS4tW3/1)